# can't find data from the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have huge database that consist of more than 200,000 rows and the problem i'm facing is that whenever i'm running in my loaclhost, it shows accurate results but when ever i'm in a server it misses out some results..

The problem is shown below...

when ever i enter ip in my localhost it shows the output

but whenever i run the same ip in the server it shows no results

The link to my server is http://ip2country.1eko.com/index.php

the query code is shown below..

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
$ip = ip2long($_REQUEST['ip']);

$res = mysql_query("SELECT * from ip2country WHERE $ip BETWEEN begin_long_ip AND end_long_ip") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
echo "<h1>Country Name :  ".$row['country_name']."</h1><br />";
echo "<h1>Country Code :  ".$row['country_code']."</h1><br />";

$res1 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total FROM ip2country") or die(mysql_error());
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($res1);
echo $row1['Total'];

}
```

?>

Any help will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: `ip` is not just a number, right? You can't use `between` like that.

Comment: juergen, looks like he converted it to `long` with the line `$ip = ip2long($_REQUEST['ip']);` if I'm not mistaken.

Subhomoy, do you have `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` ? Try `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and check the `mysql` extension is loaded on your server.

Also `mysql_*` is deprecated and you should really be using mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: i have used ip2long function to convert the ip to number...

Comment: yes @Matt you r right...

Comment: `WHERE $ip BETWEEN begin_long_ip AND end_long_ip` can you please enlighten me how is this spposed to work?

Comment: I'm finding the ip between those two ranges (bengin_long_ip and end_long_ip).. and whenever they fall in that category, it will show the result...

Answer (score 0):

You did not get my comment, so here is explanation.
Its not hard to see nasty error on your page:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BETWEEN begin_long_ip AND end_long_ip' at line 1`

and that is bacause your query is wrong:

`SELECT * from ip2country WHERE $ip BETWEEN begin_long_ip AND end_long_ip`

You should change it like this:

`SELECT * from ip2country WHERE $ip > begin_long_ip AND $ip < end_long_ip`

PS. Please be aware taht mysql_* functions are deprecated and you should not use them anymore. Try Mysqli/ PDO instead.

Comment: As far as i know they both work the same...
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Comment: I might be blind, but I cant see part where you can use column names as between values...

Comment: May be i've mistaken but then how dies it work well in my localhost... It works perfect without any error... How come this be possible...

Comment: @MarkS `BETWEEN` is perfectly valid in MySQL [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2d7b1/2)